# Displaying Application Icons (and names) in ListView Object

Tags: vb.net, icons, ms-office

I,

I'm creating a VB Form with a ListView object containing Images of Excel, Word or Pdf Icons, with a link to the displayed document (to be made)

When compilating, the names of the documents are displayed in the listView but not the icons. Do you know what is missing in my code?

As far as I understand, the "ExtractAssociatedIcon" method needs the full path to the file, but it seems that no Icon is collected here.

Thanks

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Drawing
```

[...]

```
        Dim dirInfo As DirectoryInfo
        Dim fileInfo As FileInfo
        Dim exePath As String
        Dim exeIcon As Drawing.Icon

        dirInfo = New DirectoryInfo("G:\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX")

        'We use this For...Each to iterate over the collection of files in the folder
         For Each fileInfo In dirInfo.GetFiles
        'We can only find associated exes by extension, so don't show any files that have no extension
        If fileInfo.Extension = String.Empty Then
        Else
            'Use the function to get the path to the executable for the file
            exePath = fileInfo.FullName


            'Use ExtractAssociatedIcon to get an icon from the path
            exeIcon = Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(exePath)

            'Add the icon if we haven't got it already, with the executable path as the key

            If ImageList1.Images.ContainsKey(exePath) Then
            Else
                ImageList1.Images.Add(exePath, exeIcon)

            End If

            'Add the file to the ListView, with the executable path as the key to the ImageList's image
            ListView1.View = View.LargeIcon
            ListView1.Items.Add(fileInfo.Name, exePath)
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You need to set the [SmallImageList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.smallimagelist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and/or the [LargeImageList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.largeimagelist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the `ListView`:

```
ListView1.LargeImageList = ImageList1
ListView1.SmallImageList = ImageList1
```

**2)** Put this at the top of your code. (Not in the `For Each` loop)

```
ListView1.View = View.LargeIcon
```

**3)** Also, be sure that you don't add an empty icon, nor sets an invalid image key:

```
If (ImageList1.Images.ContainsKey(exePath)) Then
    ListView1.Items.Add(fileInfo.Name, exePath)
ElseIf (Not exeIcon Is Nothing) Then
    ImageList1.Images.Add(exePath, exeIcon)
    ListView1.Items.Add(fileInfo.Name, exePath)
Else
    ListView1.Items.Add(fileInfo.Name)
End If
```

**Example**

The following code is tested and works fine:

```
ListView1.LargeImageList = ImageList1
ListView1.SmallImageList = ImageList1
ListView1.View = View.LargeIcon

Dim dirInfo As DirectoryInfo
Dim fileInfo As FileInfo
Dim exeIcon As System.Drawing.Icon

dirInfo = New DirectoryInfo("...")

For Each fileInfo In dirInfo.GetFiles
    If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileInfo.Extension)) Then

        exeIcon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fileInfo.FullName)

        If (ImageList1.Images.ContainsKey(fileInfo.FullName)) Then
            ListView1.Items.Add(fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.FullName)
        ElseIf (Not exeIcon Is Nothing) Then
            ImageList1.Images.Add(fileInfo.FullName, exeIcon)
            ListView1.Items.Add(fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.FullName)
        Else
            ListView1.Items.Add(fileInfo.Name)
        End If

    End If
Next
```